# Original CSS rgba(..) Opacity Value Modified on iPhone 7 with an Approximate Value

Tags: html, css, iphone

In my CSS I define a style that includes rgba(..) with an Opacity value, as follows:

```
.eventcolor-0{
     background:rgba(14, 48, 71, 0.3);
 }
```

The opacity value is 0.3. I dynamically extract the full style from the CSS using JS because I need to get the full rgba() string, and then check it.

On the desktop the style from the CSS is correct,

```
rgba(14, 48, 71, 0.3);
```

But on iPhone 7, the style comes back as:

```
rgba(14, 48, 71, 0.298039);
```

Does anyone know why this could be? The iPhone modifies my original CSS value for Opacity for that style without my knowledge, 0.3 --> 0.298039. I do not have that 0.298039 anywhere in my CSS.

---

(FYI, in case you're wondering how I'm extracting CSS Style definitions, I'm using this utility function to scan my styles in JS)

```
// A utility function to get a specific style from a CSS (will scan all available non-cross-domain CSS if not provided)
function getStyleRuleValue(style, selector, sheet) {
    var sheets = typeof sheet !== 'undefined' ? [sheet] : document.styleSheets;
    for (var i = 0, l = sheets.length; i < l; i++) {
        var sheet = sheets[i];
        if( !sheet.cssRules ) { continue; }
        for (var j = 0, k = sheet.cssRules.length; j < k; j++) {
            var rule = sheet.cssRules[j];
            if (rule.selectorText && rule.selectorText.indexOf(selector) !== -1) {
                return rule.style[style];
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Did you try HEX palette? `rgba(14, 48, 71, 0.3)` in HEX is `#0e30474d`

Comment: 255 * 0.3 = 76.5. It becomes 76 with flooring. 76/255 = 0.298039.

Comment: I don't understand, are you saying I can't rely on fixed rgba(..) definitions in my CSS, and that they won't be honored?

Comment: No, I'm saying that those two values are **the same**.

Comment: But I need the string obtained from the CSS to be exactly the same on the desktop and iPhone, because some business logic depends on checking that full rgba(..) string and matching it. It is exactly the same on the desktop (Windows 10), but not the same on iPhone 7.

Comment: @geneb. Ceil it! :)

Comment: If precision is important, store the colors in hexadecimal values, as JaxCze said.

Comment: JaxCze, where did you get the last `4d` part from? All the sites give me `#0e3047` for that color, without your last two characters `4d`.

Comment: That 4d part is the alpha value.